How can I instantiate prefabs from a non-MonoBehaviour script?
I'm trying to instantiate prefabs in Unity, but I want to do it from a script that doesn't inherit from MonoBehaviour.
I understand that a MonoBehaviour is typically required to use methods like Instantiate, but is there any way to perform this action from a non-MonoBehaviour class?

If you search for Unity Instantiate, you'll find the docs for the Instantiate function, showing that it's a static function on the UnityEngine.Object type.
So, you can just write:
var instance = UnityEngine.Object.Instantate(prefab);

(If you have using UnityEngine at the top of your file, then Object.Instantiate will suffice)

But how can I initialize a variable in the inspector on a static class? How can the script know what prefab is?

@CheckerT You can't do that in the inspector, because static classes can not be assigned to game objects. But there are other ways to obtain a reference to a prefab at runtime. For example, you could acquire it as an Addressable, or you can receive the reference from a GameObject that is in the scene. If you want a more detailed answer to your followup question, please post it as a new question.
